# Variable number of decimal digits in string.format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to transform this:

```
my_number = 3.1415928

if precision == 2:
    my_string = "{0:.2f}".format(my_number)
elif precision == 3:
    my_string = "{0:.3f}".format(my_number)
elif precision == 4:
    my_string = "{0:.4f}".format(my_number)
elif precision == 5:
    my_string = "{0:.5f}".format(my_number)
```

Into something like this:

```
my_number = 3.1415928

my_string = "{SOMETHING_DEPENDING_ON_PRECISION_HERE}".format(my_number)
```

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

in addition to Vaultah's (excellent) suggestion you can do it with the splat with old style formating as well

```
precision = 2
my_num = 3.1415928
my_string = "%0.*f"%(precision,my_num)
```

Vaultah's (now shredded suggestion)

```
"{0:0.{prec}f}".format(my_num,prec=precision)
```

Comment: What if I wanted the minimum number of decimals necessary?

Comment: use `"%g"` and it will truncate non-meaningful digits